# Canada Visitor Visa Family Application?

Tags: visas, canada

We want to visit Canada on a short-term visitor visa for tourism. We are a family of 4 but we have a family friend traveling with us. I will financially support all 5 of us. While applying for the VISA online and filling the questionnaire, it asks for additional family members traveling with me and their documents so shall I include our family friend in the same list? If not, how do we process it otherwise?

I am not sure how it works with Canada but all 5 of us applied for a USA VISA in the same way in a single application. I just had to mention the people traveling with me, we applied as a group and went for interview together. We were granted the VISA successfully.

Comment: Any answer to my question would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as it [duplicates your later question] which was answered and accepted (thank you). Enjoy your trip to Canada.

Comment: @Dorothy yes sure